# Amcharts: change entire dataset

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am starting using amcharts 4 and I have run into issue: according to the docs to change charts dataset all it takes is to assign new array of objects to the chart.data:

```
chart.data = [{ some data object }, {}......]
```

It does it seems to be working for me, please see this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LMgEjV

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 *
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 *
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "Lithuania",
  "litres": 501.9
}, {
  "country": "Czech Republic",
  "litres": 301.9
}, {
  "country": "Ireland",
  "litres": 201.1
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "litres": 165.8
}, {
  "country": "Australia",
  "litres": 139.9
}, {
  "country": "Austria",
  "litres": 128.3
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "litres": 99
}, {
  "country": "Belgium",
  "litres": 60
}, {
  "country": "The Netherlands",
  "litres": 50
}];

// Add and configure Series
var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "litres";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "country";

function changeData() {
  chart.data = [{
    "country": "Lithuania",
    "litres": 501.9
   }, {
      "country": "Czech Republic",
      "litres": 301.9
    }
  ];
  
  chart.validateData();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<button id="btn-change" onClick="changeData()">Click Me</button>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understood the problem but I will try to help you anyway, I checked your code and I think the main problem happened because you push entire array to the `chart.data` instead of just the object you want to change. please see my code:

```
function changeData() {
    chart.data.push({
        "country": "Lithuania",
        "litres": "501.9"
       })

 chart.validateData();
}
```

Comment: Hi Tomer, what I need to do is to replace the entire dataset, not add another item. 
The documentation says that assigning new object should do the trick but something is not working here 
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Replacing_whole_data_set

Comment: Hi kathrine0, I tried to look again at your code, and now for some reason, it is working, I took your code and I didn't change it this time, and when I press the button the whole data is changing to the new data. this is very strange

Comment: They seemed to fix it over the weekend: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/commit/878b81d8b81f9eb65e51f77912e25da83778e281

Quoting the changelog: "### Fixed
- Chart with `ColumnSeries` was failing with an error when `data` was updated."